# How can I Add Numbers one by one by clicking a button in EditText?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-edittext, android-button

I am making my first app in android that is a simple calculator.

When I press button '1' then it shows "1" in EditText, but when I press it again it doesn't show "11", it shows only "1".

How can I fix this?

Comment: past your code to I try help please

Answer (score 2):

Since you've offered no code I can only take a stab in the dark and guess that you're calling `setText()` on your `EditText` which would overwrite whatever was in there in the first place.  What you would need to get is something like:

```
myEdit.setText(myEdit.getText + "1");
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code on button click.use `append` method to add text number in editview as:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText.append("1");
```

and you can use:

```
editText.setText(editText.GetText() + title);
```

Comment: append would be appropriate.+1

Comment: ohh thanks a lot... appned is working as i want... thanks again

Comment: welcome friend!!!,if it's working then accept as answer for others help which looking for same problems.thanks

Answer (score 1):

you are probably replacing the contents of the `EditText` completely, while what you want to do is append to it ... something like,

```
oneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    editText.setText(editText.getText().toString() + "1");
  }
}
```